# Why is Core Data loading two persistent stores?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to do some simple `Core Data` unit tests.
But from what I can see there are two persistent stores created (both sql type), so my `setup(), tearDown()` unit test methods are called twice, reseting the `NSManagedObjectContext` thus causing some issues.

Here is my code to load the stores:

```
func createContainer(storeType: StoreType, completion: @escaping (NSPersistentContainer) -> ()) {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Gym")

    container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            fatalError("Failed to load store \(error!)")
        }

        description.type = storeType.type

        completion(container)
    }
}
```

And this is my unit test code:

```
import XCTest
import CoreData
@testable import Gym

class GymTests: XCTestCase {

    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        createContainer(storeType: .inMemory) { container in
            self.context = container.viewContext
        }
    }

    func testAddingExercise() {
        // Given
        context.performChanges {
            _ = Exercise.insert(into: self.context, name: "Bench Press", groups: Set(["Chest", "Triceps", "Shoulders"]))
            _ = Exercise.insert(into: self.context, name: "Squats", groups: Set(["Legs"]))
            _ = Exercise.insert(into: self.context, name: "Deadlifts", groups: Set(["Back", "Legs", "Arms"]))
        }

        // When
        let exercises = Exercise.fetch(in: context)

        // Then
        XCTAssertEqual(exercises.count, 3)
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        context = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }
}
```

The second time it runs my test, the context was reset in `tearDown()` so context will be nil when adding exercises.

Not sure exactly how is this happening. Why is it creating two stores ?

Comment: What is the problem? Note that the code in `setUp` runs before each test, and `tearDown` after each test. Each test will get a new container and context. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @MikeTaverne: managed to fix it, apparently the issue was that I was adding data async instead of sync, so by the time I use XCTAssertEqual, the data was not added yet.